# Need help fixing javascript for creating individual click events on form page with multiple file upload inputs

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a Gravity Form containing multiple file upload fields.

When a user clicks the button (modified label) the div container holding the file input has the file name appended to it.

My problem is that based on the tutorial I used to restyle the fields and set up, the javascript only targets the first file input and the others won't work when they are clicked.

How do I fix my code so that the javascript is listening to all file inputs, not just the first?

(I was trying to attach the filename to an existing div in the container. If you know a better way I'm open)

Some screenshots

1. four file upload fields

[image]

2. When I click first field button, filename appears successfully. When I click remaining field buttons, no filename appears

[image]

The issue seems to be around using .querySelector() which only targets the first file input on the page.

I've tried that, also using getElementsByClassName, iterating through a loop using querySelectorAll. But can't quite figure it out

Using .querySelector()

HTML

```
<li id="field_3_9" class="gfield gfield_upload w-100 field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
  <label class="gfield_label" for="input_3_9">upload file</label>
  <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_fileupload">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="52428800">
    <input name="input_9" id="input_3_9" type="file" class="medium" aria-describedby="validation_message_3_9 live_validation_message_3_9 extensions_message_3_9" onchange="javascript:gformValidateFileSize( this, 52428800 );" tabindex="55">
    <span id="extensions_message_3_9" class="screen-reader-text"></span>
    <div class="validation_message" id="live_validation_message_3_9">pdf test.pdf</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Javascript

```
var inputLabel = document.querySelector('.gfield_label');
var inputWrapper = document.querySelector('.gfield_upload');
var input =  document.querySelector("input[type='file']");
var inputSuccess = document.querySelector('.validation_message');

input.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const name = input.value.split(/\\|\//).pop();
  const truncated = name.length > 20 
    ? name.substr(name.length - 20) 
    : name;

    inputSuccess.innerHTML = truncated;
});
```

Tried with .querySelectorAll()

```
  var inputWrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.gfield_upload');

  Array.from(inputWrapper).forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var realInput =  document.querySelector("input[type='file']");
        var inputSuccess = document.querySelector('.validation_message');

        realInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
            const name = realInput.value.split(/\\|\//).pop();
            const truncated = name.length > 20 
              ? name.substr(name.length - 20) 
              : name;

            inputSuccess.innerHTML = truncated;
        });
    });
});
```

My expectations are when I click the upload button for any of the file input fields, the file name will be appended to the input container and visible on the screen.

Comment: Maybe use querySelectorAll to select all file inputs `var input =  document.querySelectorAll("input[type='file']");`

Comment: @tcj  I tried that before with no luck. updated original post to show code

Comment: On your updated code, you're doing a `querySelectorAll` on `.gfield_upload` not on `"input[type='file']"` to get all file inputs.

Comment: "The issue seems to be around using .querySelector() which only targets the first file input on the page." <= doing a `var input = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='file']");` fixes that issue...

Comment: the issue is when I try the querySelectorAll it then throws an error saying the the input.addEventListener isn't a function

Answer (score 0):

Your querySelectorAll solution is almost working, you are just querying from the wrong root element.

[image: you should use input.querySelector instead of document.querySelector]